# Otimização de tempo de consulta SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, otimização

Tenho um banco de dados que armazena precipitações marcadas por vários sensores em determinadas datas e horas, no decorrer de um ano. Estou fazendo uma consulta, para buscar todos os registros marcados por um únicos sensor, com a seguinte instrução `SELECT p.latitude, p.longitude, h.precipitacaoh, h.datah, h.horah FROM pontos AS p, historico AS h WHERE p.gid = 913` e o tempo gasto é em torno de 9.36 minutos. Porém são 1517 sensores e preciso recuperar todos os registros de cada um deles, o que totalizaria mais ou menos 9 dias buscando todos estes registros. Alguém sabe um jeito diminua este tempo de consulta?

Comment: `gid` é a chave primária da tabela? Quantos registros mais ou menos retornam após esse tempo?

Comment: Gosto bastante desse tutorial. http://imasters.com.br/artigo/22264/banco-de-dados/10-tecnicas-para-otimizacao-de-instrucoes-sql/?trace=1519021197&source=single

Comment: isso, gid é a chave primária da tabela pontos, depois de 9,36 minutos retorna um total de 4429640 registros @Sorack

Comment: Obrigada @Marconi, vou dar uma olhada

Comment: Não falta uma ligação entre a tabela dos pontos e do histórico? Assim está a criar um cross join.

Comment: @RenatoAfonso na verdade, primeiro estou fazendo `SELECT DISTINCT gid, latitude, longitude FROM pontos` faço um for pra percorrer cada sensor e dentro do for coloco a seguinte consulta `SELECT datah, horah, precipitacaoh FROM historico WHERE gidgeo_fk = %d"%(contSensor[0])` para pegar o histórico de cada sensor